# Special characters (* and ?) doesnt work in PPT-file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a macro for editing report in PowerPoint. There are a date on Title slide. I want to find the date and replace by new one. Doing this such way:

```vb
    For i = 1 To pptTitle.Shapes.Count
        If pptTitle.Shapes(i).HasTextFrame = True Then
            Set txtRange = pptTitle.Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange
            txtStr = txtRange.Text
            If txtRange.Text Like "*??.??.????*" Then
                txtRange.Replace FindWhat:="??.??.????*", replaceWhat:=ind_date
                txtRange.Text = Replace(txtRange.Text, "*??.??.????*", ind_date, 1, vbTextCompare)
                txtRange.Text = Replace(txtRange.Text, "*? 20??", ind_date2, 1, vbTextCompare)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

The key problem connected with .Find(* or ?). In Excel I have used them if I don't know exact character or number of characters. However here this doesn't work. I have no reasons why.

Maybe there are any specifics connected with PPT or I had any error, but I want to understand how to use question mark and asterisk sing in .Find Function

Comment: I'm not sure `*` or `?` are supported in PPT. Regex could be an option.

Comment: You can test a string with something like this: If sTest Like "*.*.????*" Then  But first you'd have to isolate the string, possibly by repeated calls to InStr to find periods in the middle of the string, then Mid$ to construct something to use in sTest above.

Comment: it seems that ppt Like supports wildcards, but Replace does not and you need to change use of Replace